# Get links photos and insert another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, thanks for helping me. My English is not very good
I want people to help me. How to grab photos of the `class="swiper-slide"` to insert `class="tt1"`?

Ex:

```
<div class="tt1"></div>    
<div class="tt11">...</div>
<div class="tt2">
    <div class="tt3">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="tt1">
    <img src="/image1.jpg">
</div>    
<div class="tt11">...</div>
<div class="tt2">
    <div class="tt3">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again thank you for helping me !

Comment: Only image of first `.swiper-slide`?

Comment: Yes :) 
I just 1 images, Only image of first !

Comment: Use `$(".swiper-slide:first").find("img").appendTo(".tt1")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are looking for something like this but take a look.

```js
$(".swiper-slide").each(function(){
  $(".tt1:eq(0)").append($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tt1"></div>    
<div class="tt11">...</div>
<div class="tt2">
<div class="tt3">
  <br><br>
/--- ss ---/
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="/image1.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="/image2.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="/image3.jpg" style="width: 225px; height: 400px;">
</div>
/--- ss ---/
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just 1 images , Only image of first :)

Answer (score 1):

**For grabbing first image**

Method 1 : `$(".tt1").append($(".swiper-slide").html());`

Method 2 :`$(".tt1").append($(".swiper-slide:nth-child(1)").html());`

**For grabbing all images under class swiper-slide**

```
 var swiperImage = '';
 $(".swiper-slide").each(function() {
   swiperImage += $(this).html();
 });
 $(".tt1").append(swiperImage);
```

Comment: I just 1 images , Only image of first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this Jquery to get each `img` element and insert it at the end of `.tt1`:

```
$(".swiper-slide img").each(function(i){
    $(".tt1").append($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: I just 1 images , Only image of first :)